# Data Showing on Console but not on Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, js

if i select one or more than one checkbox then their account records should be show on subscriber component
[image]

Here is the Code   ====HTML====

```
    <template>  
        <lightning-card  variant="Narrow"  title="AccountCheckboxsubscriber" icon-name="standard:account">
            <p> AccountCheckboxsubscriber </p> <br>
        <template for:each={accc} for:item="acc">                
            <lightning-card key={acc.Id} title={acc.Name} icon-name="standard:case">
              <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
              Account Name:  {acc.Name} </br>
              Type: {acc.Type} </br>
              Website: {acc.Website} </br>    
            </div> 
            </lightning-card>
        </template>
        </lightning-card>
    </template>
```

=======JS========

```
import { LightningElement,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { registerListener } from 'c/pubsub';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getAccountss from '@salesforce/apex/AccountCheckboxLWC.getAccountss';

export default class AccountCheckboxsubscriber extends LightningElement {
    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;
    
    @track accountvalues;
    @track error;
    @track accc = [];
    
connectedCallback() {
    // subscribe to eventdetails event
    registerListener('eventdetails', this.accDetails, this);
}

accDetails(data){
    this.accountvalues = data;
    console.log('>>>>>accountvalues '+this.accountvalues);

// for fetching account Records 

getAccountss({accountId:this.accountvalues})
    .then(result=>{
        console.log('result--'+JSON.stringify(result));
        this.accc.push(result);
        console.log('>>>this.accc '+JSON.stringify(this.accc));

    })
    .catch(error=>{
        console.log('Error--'+error);
    })    
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAccountss` returns a list of Account, so pushing the result in `accc` array results in an array of array. Indeed the console log shows:

```js
this.accc
[
   [
        {"Id": "0012...", "Name": "qwertgvc", "Type": "Prospect", ... }
   ]
]
```

Therefore the item `acc` in the template holds an array, that has no properties like `Name`, `Type` and `Website`, so you see nothing.

You could use [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals) when pushing the result of `getAccountss` methods into `accc` to have a flat array:

```js
getAccountss({accountId:this.accountvalues})
    .then(result=>{
        console.log('result--'+JSON.stringify(result));
        this.accc.push(...result); // Applied spread syntax here
        console.log('>>>this.accc '+JSON.stringify(this.accc));

    })
    .catch(error=>{
        console.log('Error--'+error);
    })
```

Comment: can you help me with this too https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/400856/123606