# In LWC I Want to remove the specific data on unchecking the checkbox I'm Using Pub Sub to Connect two Component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, js

Whenever i checking the checkbox then their result is showing in other component

[image]

But now i want to remove the Acme Account so i Uncheck this but the Edge Communication is removing (means Last Checked Account record)

[image]

i first checked the Acme then the Edge Communication and now i'm Unchecking Edge Communications First(Last Checked Account) so its working Fine

[image]

My Problem is=====
I am trying to whenever i uncheck the specific record that should be removed from the other component not the Last Checked Account. we can take example from these images as well. if i want to remove Acme then only Acme should be remove not the Edge Communications.

AccountCheckboxPublisher  JS ========

```
import { LightningElement,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import getAccRec from '@salesforce/apex/AccountCheckboxLWC.getAccRec';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { fireEvent } from 'c/pubsub';
export default class AccountCheckboxPublisher extends LightningElement {
    
    @wire (getAccRec) accData;
    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;
    accData;
    @track getAccId;
     
    handleChangeRadio(event){    
       var checkBox = event.target.checked;
       console.log('>>>chekcBox '+checkBox);   //  Checkbox Value true / false

       if(checkBox == true){

        this.getAccId = event.target.value;     // account record id
        window.console.log('getAccId ' + this.getAccId); 

        var accId = this.getAccId;
        console.log('>>>>accId '+accId);

        fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'eventdetails', accId);
   
       }
       else if(checkBox == false){
           console.log('>>> Else Condition for checkbox');

               fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'eventdetails', accId); 
       }
        
    }
}
```

AccountCheckboxsubscriber   JS=========

```
import { LightningElement,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { registerListener } from 'c/pubsub';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getAccountss from '@salesforce/apex/AccountCheckboxLWC.getAccountss';

export default class AccountCheckboxsubscriber extends LightningElement {
    @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;
   
    @track accountvalues;
    @track error;
    @track accc = [];

connectedCallback() {
    // subscribe to eventdetails event
    registerListener('eventdetails', this.accDetails, this);
}

accDetails(data){
    this.accountvalues = data;
    console.log('>>>>>accountvalues '+this.accountvalues);

// for fetching account Records
getAccountss({accountId:this.accountvalues})
    .then(result=>{
        console.log('result--'+JSON.stringify(result)); // if we are unchecking the checkbox then result is null 

    if(result.length){     // if result is having some data then Push the data in List
        this.accc.push(...result);
        console.log('>>>this.accc '+JSON.stringify(this.accc)); 
        }
            else if(result.length === 0){       // if result = null then pop the list value
        console.log('>>> Result is Blank >>>>');
        var index = this.accc.indexOf(this.accc);
        this.accc.splice(index);
        console.log('>>> index '+index);

    }   
    })
    .catch(error=>{
        console.log('Error--'+error);
    })      

}
}
```

Comment: Can you please add markup code as well? That would help in debugging the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you pass nothing in the event when you uncheck an account, so you cannot know which account you should remove, then in AccountCheckboxsubscriber component the following two lines will always remove the last element from the array

```js
var index = this.accc.indexOf(this.accc);
this.accc.splice(index);
```

[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) searchs for the input element and returns its index, or `-1` if it isn't present in the array. Since you're searching for the whole array (`this.accc`), it will always return `-1` (unless you push its own reference into it, but there is no reason to do that).
The first two parameters of [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) are:

1. An index at which to start changing the array. If it's negative the starting position will be `index + array.length`, so if it's `-1` the starting position will be the last element (`array.length - 1`).
2. An integer indicating the number of elements in the array to remove from the starting position. If it's omitted then all the elements from start to the end of the array will be deleted.

So calling `splice(-1)` will remove just the last element, therefore those two lines are the equivalent of [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Besides that, since you want to remove a specific account from AccountCheckboxsubscriber component, you should pass something that let you know which account should be removed, i.e. the Id you have in `event.target.value`.
You don't have to fire always the same event, you could fire a specific one for each action you want to take. Please also give meaningful names to those events, i.e. `addAccount` and `removeAccount`.
Of course you have to register a listeren for both events and in the remove one you could [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your array.

These advices translates into the following code:

**AccountCheckboxPublisher**

```js
handleChangeRadio(event) {    
    const add = event.target.checked;
    console.log('>>>add ', add); //  Checkbox Value true / false
    const accountId = event.target.value;
    console.log('>>>>accountId ', accountId);
    
    this.getAccId = accountId; // If this.getAccId is used only in this method, that property and this line can be removed 

    if(add) {
        fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'addAccount', accountId);
    }
    else { // no need to check whether boolean is false
        console.log('>>> Else Condition for checkbox');
        fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'removeAccount', accountId); 
    }
}
```

**AccountCheckboxsubscriber**

```js
connectedCallback() {
    // subscribe to addaccount event
    registerListener('addAccount', this.accDetails, this);
    // subscribe to removeaccount event
    registerListener('removeAccount', this.removeAccount, this);
}

accDetails(data){
    this.accountvalues = data;
    console.log('>>>>>accountvalues '+this.accountvalues);

    // for fetching account Records
    getAccountss({ accountId: this.accountvalues })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('result--'+JSON.stringify(result));

            if (result.length) {     // if result is having some data then Push the data in List
                this.accc.push(...result);
                console.log('>>>this.accc '+JSON.stringify(this.accc)); 
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error--'+error);
        });
}

removeAccount(accountId) {
    console.log('removeAccount - Id:', accountId);
    this.accc = this.accc.filter((account) => account.Id != accountId);
}
```

Just a last thing, if those components are in the same lightning page, you could use [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-message-channel.html) instead of pubsub.

Comment: Thank You Now its working fine.